# Center divs next to eachother automatically

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML snippet:

```
<div id="main">
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="middle"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/1osmm3r3/

The problem is that, I have width: 80% on the main div and specific `px` for the middle div. What can I do to keep the middle div in the center of the main div, and the left and right div automatically take up the rest of the space? Using `margin-left` and `margin-right` set to `auto` on the middle div seems to not move it at all, I need to put it with numbers.

this is how i want it to look:
[image]

Comment: It looks right on the link you have provided

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `display: flex`. Read more about flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#main #left {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: coral;
}
#main #middle {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: forestgreen;
}
#main #right {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="left">Left</div>
  <div id="middle">middle</div>
  <div id="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 But the flex-direction property is must here... read more http://dipaksblogonline.blogspot.in/2014/05/css-flexbox-explained-with-examples.html

Comment: @Dipak : Updated the answer. But it's not mandatory, becoz initial value will be `row`. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction.

Answer (score 0):

Change Some css

```
#main
{
    border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#middle
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#right
{
    float: right;
}

#left
{
    float: left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1osmm3r3/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution to your question would be applying css **display: flex** property to div id = main.

```
#main{
   display: flex;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `float: left;` in `#middle {}` style definition solves your problem. When you are using `float` property, the `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;` properties do not apply.

Additionally, you can do a little modification in the DOM.

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="left">
        <h1>test</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        <h1>test</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/1osmm3r3/3/)

Updated the solution to match the OP's expected solution.

[**Updated FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/1osmm3r3/4/)

Comment: thank you, this becomes how I want it to be except that I want the div id="right" to be just after "middle"

Comment: Couple of questions. First, is the `#middle` div always `320px width`? Secondly, what happens if the `#main` div's width in pixel is little more or equal or less than 320px? The text of either sides have some pixel width.

Comment: the middle div will always be 320px and for the left and right box, I want them to have a % width or a fixed width somehow, so it adds up to the #mains width. in the #left there is only buttons and in the #right there will only be text

Comment: Ok. What make you set the container 80% width?

Comment: @J.Doe I made a little change in the css to match your expected solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
#main
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 80%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#middle{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
  margin:calc(100% - 80%);
    float: left;
}

#right{
    float: left;
  width:10%;
}

#left{
    float: left;
  width:10%;
}
```